# How to build an anonymouse.org clone on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, anonymize

I like the simplicity of [anonymouse.org](http://anonymouse.org/) but would like to build a free version running on Google App Engine.

What would be required to do so?

Is it complicated to completely hide someone's location?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/setup-proxy-server/12890/) is a quick guide to set up a proxy using Google App Engine.
The proxy server is based on [Mirrorr](https://mirrorrr.appspot.com/), an open-source web caching project by Brett Slatkin

You can download the source code [here](http://img.labnol.org/files/proxy.zip).